# How to try until resolve (Promise in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, timeout

lately I have been facing a connection problem that makes the connection between my code and db unstable...

[TimeOut Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQrWj.png)

As you may have noticed, that create a connection request error, and I need a way to make my Promise keep trying until resolve. 
My code:

```
var results = sqlQuery(sql)
function sqlQuery (sql) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      sql.query(/*query*/, function (error, results, fields) {
         if (error) {
            console.log(error)
            reject(error)
         }
         resolve(results)
      })
   })
}
```

**IMPORTANT :** The code above is inside a while() that change the /*query*/ in each loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a way of testing this, but try something like this, using a recursive function:

```js
var results = sqlQuery(sql)
function sqlQuery (sql) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      sql.query(/*query*/, function (error, results, fields) {
         if (error) {
            return sqlQuery(sql).then(res => resolve(res));
         }
         resolve(results)
      })
   })
}
```

Although I have to say that redoing it over and over again just isn't the best idea...